# Load file and fill a page after click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple request. I have this:

[image]

So, in my .aspx :

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="myFileUpload" runat="server" onclick="LoadFile_Click" />
```

After the pression of the "Load file" button, I want that the page will be filled with the data of the document choosen. Like this:

[image]

In my .aspx.cs

```
    protected void LoadFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string address = // a way to get the path of the file. How?
        BindExcelToPage(address); // this method fills the web page with the data taken from the file uploaded;
    }
```

- The informative phrase "No file selected" (or whatever) must be invisible. I want just the Load button.
- I don't know how to implement the starts of the event for the loading of the page.

Answer (score 0):

After you BindExcel file with page, hide your fileupload control and replace with it label(if you want use label and button) and set the filename in label. This way it looks like file is there. FileUpload control's filename is readonly, so you can't assign it.

Comment: I want an alternative to FileUpload, because I don't want the label also BEFORE the upload (I want just the load button). Furthermore, I don't know how bind the click of the botton on the event ( `onclick="LoadFile_Click"` doesn't works...)